# "invalid regular expression...reason 'Trailing backslash''' error with gsub in R

Tags: r, gsub

I am getting error message while replacing text in R.

```
 x
 [1] "Easy bruising and bleeding.\\"

gsub(as.character(x), "\\", "")
Error in gsub(as.character(x), "\\", "") : 
   invalid regular expression 'Easy bruising and bleeding.\', reason 'Trailing backslash'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The arguments are in the wrong order. Study `help("gsub")`.

```
gsub( "\\", "", "Easy bruising and bleeding.\\", fixed=TRUE)
#[1] "Easy bruising and bleeding."
```

Comment: How do you do this without fixed = TRUE, for example matching "\" as part of a larger regular expression?

Comment: I usually add backslashes until there are enough escapes.

Comment: Hah! That definitely works. I eventually figured out you need 4 `\ `s in the first argument of gsub to match 1 literal `\ ` in the string (the third argument). I'll post what I learned as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr:**
You need 4 `\`s (i.e. `\\\\`) in the first argument of `gsub` in order to find one literal `\` in the third argument of `gsub`. The overall process is:

- gsub receives `\\\\`, passes `\\`
- regex receives `\\`, searches `\`.

To avoid `fixed = TRUE`, which precludes doing more complex searches, your code should be:

```
> gsub( "\\\\", "", "Easy bruising and bleeding.\\")
[1] "Easy bruising and bleeding."
```

**Explanation:**
The reason you need 4 `\` is that `\` is a special character for the regex engine, so in order for the regex engine to find a literal `\` it needs to be passed `\\`; the first `\` indicates that the second `\` is not a special character but a `\` that should be matched literally. Thus regex receives `\\` and searches for `\` in the string.

`\` is also a special character for R, so in order for `gsub` to pass `\\` to the regex engine, `gsub` needs to be receive `\\\\`. The first `\` indicates that the second `\` is a literal `\` and not a special character; the third `\` does the same thing for the fourth `\`. Thus gsub receives `\\\\` and passes `\\` to the regex engine.

Again, the overall process is:
gsub receives `\\\\`, passes `\\`; regex receives `\\`, searches `\`.

**Note:** while the string that you gave us prints to the screen as `"Easy bruising and bleeding.\\"`, the string is actually `Easy bruising and bleeding.\`. The first `\` is actually just an escape for the second `\`. You can verify this with this code:

```
> cat("Easy bruising and bleeding.\\")
Easy bruising and bleeding.\
```

That's why the code I suggest has 4 `\`s and not 8 `\`s.

Comment: Is there any function that can change the simple backslashes of a path directory from  `\ -> /`  ?

Comment: I use an RStudio snippet when I want to paste a Windows path from the clipboard. You could write a function that does the same. My code is: `snippet pp
 "\`r gsub('"', "", gsub("\\\\", "/", readClipboard()))\`"`. Be careful with the newline and tabs vs. spaces (comments won't let me fix the formatting).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation but I found this `gsub("\\\\" , "//" , r"(path)")` which I think do the job for me.

Comment: Do you know what the `r"(path)"` syntax is called? I copied my snippet from someone else's code and I don't really understand what `r` does. Thanks.

Comment: I found [this](https://discuss.python.org/t/what-does-r-define-in-file-path/3646). I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out your `r"string"` for a raw string is different from my `\`r expression\``, which is described here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets-in-the-RStudio-IDE